# Users aren't sending us feedback rating

Tags: gui-design, interface, feedback

we just launched a beta version of a website, where we included a feedback rating system.

A question, five stars and a comment box.

However, in three weeks, we had 0 feedback. Analytics show people are using the beta version.

This is how the feedback looks:

Note: Some inhouse people said they haven't noticed the question because of the colour. I agree, there's a possibility they really haven't, but that couldn't be the case for hundreds of monthly users, right? Also, the rating is sticky and follows the user.

I'm positively sure there's a stronger reason for the lack of ratings.

My personal theory is that users think they only need to click "send" when they enter a comment, but not for the rating part. Because we are used not confirming this kind of ratings.

What do you all think could be the reason and a feasible solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the color does play a major role on why they're not noticing it.
usually websites have headers and footers the same colors, and since your "rating bar" is colored the same as the header, my eyes automatically totally ignored the bar as I thought it was the footer of copyrights etc.

So I firstly suggest you change the color to a more "Eye-catchy" one " (not light green) it needs to be highlighted as it's important to you to have feedback.

Secondly, I agree that your sentence is not totally understandable, if you're saying you redesigned the interface, then make sure your sentence points out what you mean by maybe saying "How satisfied are you with the new design?" or something like that.

Lastly and most importantly, I believe the rate should not be included in a constant bar like the "cookies" one. You need to redesign it to be more catchy, (I believe a popup or a side square for rating is better to be noticed). Not to mention the timing, when I firstly load your page, the rating bar automatically appears on first load and that's not noticeable at all, you need to trigger the rating appearance action with the user's action. For example, the user spent 3+ minutes on your page, the user clicked on submit or some other key-button that will trigger the "rating window" and then it will definitely be noticed.

Comment: The only reason this is implemented as it is because it was a last-minute, temporary solution and will be replaced by a more advanced tool (like hotjar).

Basically, I am very glad that all the mentioned arguments are the same as one I had had.

Comment: if you're gonna use Hotjar then it will definitely do the trick, good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why should your users be giving feedback? You should only expect a tiny fraction of them to do that, so it's normal not getting *much* feedback. And as an aside, when you ask for feedback, please be prepared to receive it. It's really annoying when, dedicating your own time to provide a lengthly feedback sought by a company, just to discover that there was an undisclosed limitation of e.g. 200 characters.

Second, it took me a bit to notice where you wanted your feedback and, I would expect that after clicking one of those stars, it gets automatically sent, do note there's no submit (maybe it appears on clicking?)

Separately, I'm not even sure what you're asking. Maybe because I don't understand your site. You mention it's a beta website, not sure if it's a beta of a new version for an existing site, or a completely new one. Still, asking if you're "satisfied with the updated Database" is odd. Of course I would want a database to be updated, would you think I wanted an outdated one? How would I notice if it's updated or outdated? An unclear question will lead to even less answers.

Comment: Yes, when the user clicks on a star, a comment box shows. with a button "Send".

It's a beta version of the redesign.

Updated as in redesigned interface etc.

Answer (score 0):

With the current design, it appears that the only thing a user can do is rate their satisfaction on a scale of 1 to 5. Nothing signifies that they can send a comment as well. It's also unclear if the user will ever again get to rate their satisfaction with this page -- what if it's a 1 today, and a 5 tomorrow? Users might be holding back on giving a rating because they think they might only have one chance.

Alternatively, you could start with a small button that says "Feedback" or "Give Feedback" and then provide both the star rating and comment box each and every time it is clicked.